# Configure Portal for arcgis 10.4 and Web Adaptor 10.4

Tags: installation, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-portal, arcgis-web-adaptor

I am facing a issue related to configuration of `Portal for ArcGIS 10.4` and `ArcGIS Web Adaptor 10.4 (Java Platform)` hosted on `Oracle WebLogic 12c`.

I am getting this error (screen shot below)
[image]

I am using a Server with following configuration:

OS: Window 2008 R2 Enterprise

WebServer: Oracle WebLogic 12c

Java: 1.8.0_92 (64bit)

I have installed ArcGIS Server 10.4, Web Adaptor 10.4, Portal for ArcGIS 10.4 and WebLogic 12c on same VM.

I can access portal on https://system_domain_name:7443/arcgis/home/ and web adaptor on https://system_domain_name/arcgis/webadaptor

IIS is stopped to free 80 and 443 ports and WebLogic is running on 80 and 443 port as esri documentation. I can see the web adaptor options

[image]

Even it gives the option to put my portal URL, Admin User name and password of admin user.